# Convert JSON to one String (NiFi)

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a JSON like:

```json
{
  "id" : 1812854,
  "enabled" : 1,
  "date" : "2022-03-11",
  "maxClicks" : 100
}
```

I need to generate path from these properties and put it to attributes:

```
attribute_name:  id=1812854&enabled=1&date=2022-03-11&maxClicks=100
```

How can I do this? JSON can be different, like:

```json
{
  "id" : 1812854,
  "name" : "my_name"
  "date" : "2022-03-11"
}
```

So I need to convert JSON property names and values to one string.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **ExecuteScript** processor:

- `Script Engine`: `Groovy`
- `Script Body`:

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return

def toKeyValue = {
    it.collect { /$it.key=$it.value/ } join "&"
}

def res = ""
flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
  json = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
  def mapJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
  res = toKeyValue(mapJson)
  outputStream.write(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
} as StreamCallback)
session.transfer(session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'attribute_name', res), REL_SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript and assuming you dont have object properties and array properties you can do something like that:

```
const obj = {
  "id" : 1812854,
  "enabled" : 1,
  "date" : "2022-03-11",
  "maxClicks" : 100
};
const str = Object.entries(obj).map(f => f.join("=")).join("&");
console.log(str); //id=1812854&enabled=1&date=2022-03-11&maxClicks=100
```